# Electron Angular after button click, window is redirected to a nonexistent path

Tags: html, angular, electron

I created a simple profiles page that stores data into a JSON file in an Electron Angular project. However, I encounter an error when I click the save profile button.
(Using Angular 7)

Here is my profile.component.html file (Save Profile Button is at the very bottom of the code):

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<div>
    <form id="profile-editor">
        <div class="profiles-header">
          <!-- <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> -->
          Profile Editor
          <div class="profiles-control-buttons">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-editor-container">
          <div class="profile-section" id="shipping-editor">
            <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
            <div class="profile-editor-input-container">
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="fname=$event.target.value" type="text" id="first-name-sh" name="first-name-sh" placeholder="First Name" />
              </div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="lname=$event.target.value" type="text" id="last-name-sh" name="last-name-sh" placeholder="Last Name" /></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="shipping1=$event.target.value" type="text" id="shipping-address-01" name="shipping-address-01" placeholder="Address" /></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="shipping2=$event.target.value" type="text" id="shipping-address-02" name="shipping-address-02" placeholder="Apt./Suite" />
              </div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="city=$event.target.value" type="text" id="city-sh" name="city-sh" placeholder="City" /></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="zip=$event.target.value" type="text" id="zip-code-sh" name="zip-code-sh" placeholder="Zip Code" /></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <select (change)="country=$event.target.options[$event.target.options.selectedIndex].text" id="country-sh">
                  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Select Country</option>
                  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
                    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
                    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
                    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
                    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
                    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
                    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
                    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
                    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
                    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
                    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
                    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
                    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
                    <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
                    <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
                    <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
                    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                    <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
                    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
                    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
                    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
                    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
                    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
                    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
                    <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
                    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
                    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
                    <option value="CN">China</option>
                    <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
                    <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
                    <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
                    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
                    <option value="CD">DRC</option>
                    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
                    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
                    <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
                    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
                    <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
                    <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
                    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
                    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
                    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
                    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
                    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
                    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
                    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
                    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
                    <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
                    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
                    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
                    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
                    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
                    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                    <option value="FR">France</option>
                    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
                    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
                    <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
                    <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
                    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
                    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
                    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
                    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
                    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
                    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
                    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
                    <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
                    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
                    <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
                    <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
                    <option value="VA">Vatican</option>
                    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
                    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
                    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
                    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
                    <option value="IN">India</option>
                    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="IR">Iran</option>
                    <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
                    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                    <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
                    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
                    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
                    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                    <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
                    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
                    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
                    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
                    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
                    <option value="KP">North Korea</option>
                    <option value="KR">South Korea</option>
                    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
                    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                    <option value="LA">Laos</option>
                    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
                    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
                    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
                    <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
                    <option value="LY">Libya</option>
                    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
                    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
                    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                    <option value="MO">Macao</option>
                    <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
                    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
                    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
                    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
                    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
                    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
                    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
                    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
                    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
                    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
                    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
                    <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
                    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                    <option value="FM">Micronesia</option>
                    <option value="MD">Moldova</option>
                    <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
                    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
                    <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
                    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
                    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
                    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
                    <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
                    <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
                    <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
                    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
                    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
                    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
                    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
                    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
                    <option value="NU">Niue</option>
                    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
                    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
                    <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
                    <option value="PW">Palau</option>
                    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
                    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
                    <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
                    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
                    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
                    <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
                    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
                    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
                    <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
                    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
                    <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
                    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
                    <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
                    <option value="SH">Saint Helena</option>
                    <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                    <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
                    <option value="MF">Saint Martin</option>
                    <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                    <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                    <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
                    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
                    <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
                    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
                    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
                    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
                    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
                    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                    <option value="SX">Sint Maarten</option>
                    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
                    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
                    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
                    <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
                    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
                    <option value="GS">South Georgia</option>
                    <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
                    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
                    <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
                    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
                    <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
                    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                    <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                    <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
                    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
                    <option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
                    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
                    <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
                    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
                    <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
                    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
                    <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
                    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
                    <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
                    <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
                    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
                    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
                    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
                    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="US">United States</option>
                    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
                    <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
                    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
                    <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
                    <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
                    <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                    <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                    <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
                    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
                    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
                    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
                </select></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <select (change)="state=$event.target.options[$event.target.options.selectedIndex].text" id="state-sh">
                  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Select State</option>
                  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                  <option value="CA">California</option>
                  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                  <option value="NY">New York</option>
                  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select></div>
   
    
          <div class="profile-section" id="payment-editor">
            <h3>Payment Information</h3>
            <div class="profile-editor-input-container">
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="cardholder=$event.target.value" type="text" name="card-name" placeholder="Name on Card"/></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="cardnumber=$event.target.value" type="text" id="card-number" name="card-number" placeholder="Card Number"
                (onkeypress)="formatCard()" (onkeyup)="formatCardNumber=$event.target.value;"/></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="expiry=$event.target.value" type="text" id="card-expire" name="card-expire" placeholder="10 / 19"
                  onkeyup="formatCardExpire(event);" maxlength="5"/></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="cvv=$event.target.value" type="text" id="card-code" name="card-code" placeholder="CVV" /></div>
    
              <div class="main-newtask-checkbox-container two-col">
                <!-- <div class="newtask-checkbox-container">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="limit-checkbox" name="limit-checkbox" />
                  <label for="limit-checkbox">One Checkout Per Site</label>
                </div> -->
                <!-- <div class="newtask-checkbox-container">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="cod-checkbox" name="cod-checkbox" />
                  <label for="cod-checkbox">Supreme JP (Cash On Delivery)</label>
                </div> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          
    
          <div class="profile-section" id="profile-info-editor">
            <h3>Profile Information</h3>
            <div class="profile-editor-input-container profile-basic">
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="profilename=$event.target.value" type="text" id="profile-title" name="profile-title" placeholder="Profile Title" /></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="email=$event.target.value" type="email" id="profile-email" name="profile-email" placeholder="Order Email" /></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper">
                <input (input)="phonenumber=$event.target.value" type="text" mask='(000) 000-0000' id="phone-number" name="phone-number" placeholder="Phone Number"/></div>
              <div class="single-input-wrapper"></div>
              <div class="main-newtask-checkbox-container two-col">
                <div class="newtask-checkbox-container">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="jig-phone-checkbox" name="jig-phone-checkbox" />
                  <label for="jig-phone-checkbox">Jig Phone Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="newtask-checkbox-container">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="dot-trick-checkbox" name="dot-trick-checkbox" disabled />
                  <label for="dot-trick-checkbox">Dot Trick</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="profile-section" id="action-buttons">
            <div class="button-wrapper">
              <button (click)="saveProfile()" id="save-profile" class="profiles-save-btn-color">Save
                Profile</button>
              <button id="clear-profile" type="button" type="reset" class="profiles-clear-btn-color"><i
                  class="fas fa-broom"></i>Clear
                Fields</button>
              <button id="random-profile" class="profiles-randomize-btn-color" type="button"><i
                  class="fas fa-dice"></i>Randomize
                Values</button>
            </div>
          </div>
    
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
</html>
```

Here is my profile.component.ts file:

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';



@Component({
  selector: 'profiles',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  fname : string;
  lname : string;
  shipping1 : string;
  shipping2 : string;
  city : string;
  zip : string;
  country : string;
  state : string;
  cardholder : string;
  cardnumber : string;
  expiry : string;
  cvv : string;
  profilename : string;
  email : string;
  phonenumber : string;
  formatCardNumber : string;

  constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  saveProfile(){

    let profile  = {
      fname : this.fname,
      lname : this.lname,
      shipping1 : this.shipping1,
      shipping2 : this.shipping2,
      city : this.city,
      zip : this.zip,
      country : this.country,
      state : this.state,
      cardholder : this.cardholder,
      cardnumber : this.cardnumber,
      expiry : this.expiry,
      cvv : this.cvv,
      profilename : this.profilename,
      email : this.email,
      phonenumber : this.phonenumber
    };
    this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send('profileCreated', JSON.stringify(profile));
    console.log('Success!')
  }

}
```

After I click the save profiles button, in my dev tools, it shows that electron is sending a request to this non-existent path:

```
file:///Users/name/Bot/dist/sBot/profiles?first-name-sh=&last-name-sh=&shipping-address-01=&shipping-address-02=&city-sh=&zip-code-sh=&card-name=&card-number=&card-expire=&card-code=&profile-title=&profile-email=&phone-number=
```

Why is it redirecting me to that path and how should I address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass the click event to the click handler function 
like

```
<button (click)="saveProfile($event)" id="save-profile" class="profiles-save-btn-color">Save
                Profile</button>
```

and inside the script receive the event and prevent the default form submission using preventDefault()

```
  saveProfile(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    let profile  = {
      fname : this.fname,
      lname : this.lname,
      shipping1 : this.shipping1,
      shipping2 : this.shipping2,
      city : this.city,
      zip : this.zip,
      country : this.country,
      state : this.state,
      cardholder : this.cardholder,
      cardnumber : this.cardnumber,
      expiry : this.expiry,
      cvv : this.cvv,
      profilename : this.profilename,
      email : this.email,
      phonenumber : this.phonenumber
    };
    this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send('profileCreated', JSON.stringify(profile));
    console.log('Success!')
  }
```

Comment: Didn't fix the error. It doesn't seem to do anything besides interrupt my ipcrenderer request.

Comment: Can you pls try, $event instead of ev